# Создать триггер SQL, но он не работает. Где моя ошибка?

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

Есть таблицы `tenantsmadeutilitypayment` и `tenants`:

```
CREATE TABLE Tenants(
    PersonalAccount INT UNSIGNED, 
    SecondName VARCHAR(20),
    FirsrName VARCHAR(20),
    Patronymic VARCHAR(20),
    AmountOfRegisteredPeople TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    Privilege INT(30),
PRIMARY KEY (PersonalAccount));

create TABLE `tenantmadeutilitypayment` (
  `Receipt_id` int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateOfPay` date,
  `PersonalAccount` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Payment_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Paid_UAH` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (PersonalAccount) REFERENCES Tenants (PersonalAccount),
FOREIGN KEY (Payment_id) REFERENCES TypesOfUtilityPayments (Payment_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Receipt_id`));
```

Данные в таблицах :

```
INSERT INTO tenants (SecondName,FirstName, Patronymic, AmountOfRegisteredPeople,Privilege, personalAccount) 
    VALUES
    ('Crew','Alexey','Igorevich','2','5','44098'),
    ('Firth','John','Sergeevich','1','1','44099'),
    ('Macros','Karl','Marsovich','3','6','44100'),
    ('Turol','Veronika','Eduardovna','1','13','44101'),
    ('Irden','Tatyana','Viktorovna','2','0','44102'),
    ('Wex','Igor','Kilimov','2','0','44103'),
    ('Exort','Inna','Sergeevna','3','30','44104'),
    ('Whither','Vladimir','Ilich','2','15','44105'),
    ('Loopin','Kostya','Vyacheslavovich','3','17','44106'),
    ('Chick','Vladislav','Bogdanovich','1','0','44107'),
    ('Gray','Egor','Sergeevich','4','10','44108'),
    ('Hopin','Ilya','Vasilevich','2','3','44109'),
    ('Iriya','Inna','Antonovna','2','4','44110'),
    ('Kai`sa','Darya','Antonovna','1','1','44111'),
    ('Fillit','Nastya','Igorevna','1','12','44112');


INSERT INTO tenantmadeutilitypayment (Receipt_id, DateOfPay, Paid_UAH, Payment_id, PersonalAccount)
    VALUES
    ('001','2020-09-03','38.00','100','44098'),
    ('002','2020-10-05','45.47','101','44099'),
    ('003','2020-08-21','36.50','102','44100'),
    ('004','2020-09-30','37.43','103','44101'),
    ('005','2020-09-28','39.36','104','44102'),
    ('006','2020-09-03','39.00','105','44103'),
    ('007','2020-10-07','25.00','106','44104'),
    ('008','2020-11-09','50.98','107','44105'),
    ('009','2020-09-10','40.40','108','44106'),
    ('010','2020-08-13','33.76','109','44107'),
    ('011','2020-10-23','29.66','110','44108'),
    ('012','2020-11-24','38.00','111','44109'),
    ('013','2020-09-26','24.00','112','44110'),
    ('014','2020-09-15','38.50','113','44111'),
    ('015','2020-08-15','40.00','114','44112');
```

Отдельным запросом создаю столбец `TRIGG`

```
ALTER TABLE tenantmadeutilitypayment ADD (TRIGG VARCHAR(50));
```

Главная задача : требуется создать триггер, который будет брать

```
CONCAT( tenants.SecondName, " ", LEFT ( tenants.FirstName, 1 ), ". ", LEFT ( tenants.Patronymic, 1 )
```

И вставлять в таблицу `tenantmadeutilitypayment.TRIGG` соответствующие данные.

Я создал следующий триггер, но где-то есть ошибка. Он компилируется, но ничего не выполняет.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS add_FIO;
CREATE TRIGGER add_FIO 
AFTER INSERT
ON tenantmadeutilitypayment FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    
    DECLARE done integer default 0;
    DECLARE new_FIO VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE RESULT VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT " ";
    
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT 
    
    CONCAT( tenants.SecondName, " ", LEFT ( tenants.FirstName, 1 ), ". ", LEFT ( tenants.Patronymic, 1 ), ". " )
    FROM
    tenants
    INNER JOIN tenantmadeutilitypayment ON tenants.PersonalAccount = tenantmadeutilitypayment.PersonalAccount;
    
    
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
    OPEN cur;
    
    WHILE done = 0 DO 
        FETCH cur INTO new_FIO;
    
        IF done = 1 THEN
                UPDATE tenantmadeutilitypayment SET tenantmadeutilitypayment.TRIGG = RESULT;
        END IF;
        SET RESULT = CONCAT(RESULT, new_FIO, "; ");

    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cur;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Частичный ответ. Я изменил код, но всё же выводилась ошибка из которой я понял, что нельзя вставлять и одновременно обновлять таблицу. Возможно, что я ошибаюсь.